# Bayesian model selection with rjags

Tags: rjags

Model Image

[image]

I'm trying to do Gibbs sampling with a model in the image file using rjags.
I wrote the model as follows.

```
model {
  for (i in 1:N) {
    y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], lambda)
    mu[i] <- ((c(1, gamma)*beta)%*%X[i,])
  }
  for (i in 1:(p+1)) {
    beta[i] ~ dnorm(bhat[i], 0.00001)
  }
  for (i in 1:p) {
    gamma[i] ~ dbern(eta)
  }
  eta ~ dbeta(1,1)
  lambda ~ dgamma(v0/2, v0*s0/2)
}
```

However, gammas are all zero in the sample I have obtained.
Is there a way to fix my model to get different results?